# iOS - How to integrate my application into a browser?

Tags: ios, webkit, integration

Since I'm not even sure where and how to start solving my issue I will appreciate every smallest push to the right direction.

So, I need to write an iOS application that would keep track on some events of any or at least some webkit-based browsers, or even integrate my app's "Open with..." item into a browser's context menu.
Is it at least possible?

P.S. yeap, since there's no way to use browser extensions in iOS, I'm trying to find workarounds without need to implement my own browser but rather tiny 3-rd side application working along with some of existing browsers.

Comment: I've just discovered for myself Safari bookmarklets, but that's not what I exactly need, or at least I'm not sure that small piece of JavaScript code going as bookmarklet can be complex enough to fit my needs and replace standalone application integrated with a web-browser.

Comment: What about iOS 8 app extensions?